# How to implement self-adjusting smoothing in column generation?

Tags: heuristics, duality, column-generation

I am currently trying to implement the "Smoothing with a Self-Adjusting Parameter" methodology (on the right in Table 1) from [Pessoa et. al (2018)](https://doi.org/10.1287/ijoc.2017.0784) in my MILP. Unfortunately, I am not quite sure how to perform the individual steps. In my MILP there are the two dual vectors $\pi_{ij}$ and $\eta_{q}$, for which I would like to implement the presented self-adjusting method. I understand the initialization in step 0.

**Step 1:** Now I have to determine $\pi_{ij}^{sep}$ and $\eta_{q}^{sep}$ (in the following I will only present the specific questions for $\pi_{ij}$, since the procedure for $\eta_{q}$ is equivalent). For this I need $\pi_{ij}^{in}$ and $\pi_{ij}^{out}$. The values of $\pi_{ij}^{out}$ corresponds to $\pi_{ij}^{t}$ and $\pi_{ij}^{in}$ corresponds to $\hat{\pi_{ij}}$, which is the current imcumbent solution. Here is my first question. How do I determine this imcumbent solution $\hat{\pi_{ij}}$, i.e. what calculations do I have to do?

**Step 2:** How can I determine whether mispricing has occurred?

**Step 4:** How do I determine the subgradient of $g^{sep}(\pi_{ij}^{out}-\pi_{ij}^{in})$?

Answer (score 0):

Smoothing with self-adjusting parameter is implemented in BaPCod (https://bapcod.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) and in Coluna (https://github.com/atoptima/Coluna.jl). You can check those codes for implementation details. Concerning your questions, I do not think that it is possible to explain here better than it is already explained in the paper.

Comment: I see thank. However one question please. Does "incumbent" refer to the duals from the best known solution so far. I am asking since i only know incumbent to be the best integer solution so far, which cant be the case here, as the RMP is an LP

Comment: Incumbent here is the dual solution which "produced" the best Lagrangian bound so far.